# Values from MAT file not displayed correctly in Simulink scope

Tags: simulink

My `*.mat` file has two rows

```
time : 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
value: 1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1
```

When I plot it in a Simulink scope using the "From File" block, I get the following:

[image]

Why am I not getting the correct signal?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your solver settings, in particular your step size. I assume you are using a variable-step solver. If that's the case, change your maximum step size to something small (e.g. 0.1 or even 0.01s). By default, it's set to `auto` which is determined automatically, as the name suggests, by dividing the simulation end time by 20. If you are using a fixed-step solver, specify a smaller time step.

More on Simulink solvers at http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/types-of-solvers.html.